Raspberry Pi 5 becomes buggy without monitor
I recently purchased a Raspberry Pi 5 and attempted to use it as a server for a Node.js program. The Raspberry Pi functions properly when connected to a monitor, and when I access it via SSH from my Mac, it works well too.
However, when I disconnect the monitor from the Raspberry Pi, errors start occurring during the execution of my program. Typing on the SSH terminal becomes laggy, and eventually, my SSH connection terminates. I am unable to reconnect via SSH unless I reconnect the monitor. It seems like without the monitor, the Raspberry Pi enters some sort of sleep mode...
I tried to turn on my Raspberry with and without screen. Tried to add hdmi_force_hotplug=1 to /boot/config.txt, but nothing works. Maybe it's a power supply problem ? (I don't use the official one)

Which OS? Fully updated? Any error messages?

Debian 12, yes fully updated, no error messages

errors start occurring during the execution of my program ... we have no way to guess what they are, so tell us what they are ... error messages are extremely important

If you are not using the official Raspberry pi power supply, please get one. See if the problem disappears.

About errors, these are specific to my program, these are requests errors, but when my monitor is connected I almost have none of them. Yeah I suspect power supply too, with a more powerful one it works better but still some lags. I'll get one asap and keep you updated.

I normally use all of my Pi without a monitor so whatever you are doing it isn't because you don't have a monitor but as you have provided no details or diagnostics no one can help. Adding "hdmi_force_hotplug=1" is pointless as this is OBSOLETE.

I doubt you are using "Debian 12" - most likely Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm which is the current OS (based on Debian).

Ok just got the official power supply, it works perfectly now. It manages more things than just have enough amps. Thanks for help.
